# Javascript not working on index.php but it is working on single post's page

Tags: javascript, headers, third-party-applications

I am trying to use mathJax in my wordpress. According to the documentation at mathjax, the mathjax script url needs to mentioned in headers.php.
Which is exactly what I did. And right now this is what the head section in the headers.php looks like:

```
<head>
   <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
   <title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
   <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
        extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
        jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
        tex2jax: {
           inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
           displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
           processEscapes: true
        },
        "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
       });
    </script>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
   </script>
      <![endif]-->
  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

This javascript is not loading on my website's  [index.php](http://quantum.wobblybit.com/) page, however its loading on a [single posts page](http://quantum.wobblybit.com/nielsenchuang/exercise-4-4/). What could be the problem. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to enqueue a script is as follows:

```
function mathJax_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mathjax-js', http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML', array(), '2.7.1', false );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mathJax_scripts' );
```

I added the version number (2.7.1) and I flipped the final parameter to 'false' - that last parameter asks *'add script to footer?'*, **true** means yes, **false** means no.

Then you'll want to add the inline code into the `wp_head()`:

```
function mathJax_inlineScript() {
    <script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
        MathJax.Hub.Config({
            extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
            jax: ["input/TeX", "output/HTML-CSS"],
            tex2jax: {
                inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
                displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'], ["\\[","\\]"] ],
                processEscapes: true
            },
            "HTML-CSS": { availableFonts: ["TeX"] }
        });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'mathJax_inlineScript' , 999 );
```

In the add action I've set it to 999 - you can adjust and fine tune that to get the inline script to appear where you want it to in the `wp_head()`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

I could understand what the problem was. Firstly the statement`<script type="text/javascript"src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">` was inside an **if** for the browser IE. Even after removing that I faced the same problem because I had WP cache enabled and this was caching my webpages. So when you are testing your wp installation, I would recommend deactivating the cache.